# How to copy files from Wine to desktop?

Tags: bash, wine, games

I've files in my Wine that i would like to backup.
But Wine Explorer's GUI copy-paste is not working while copying to Desktop.

How to copy these files to desktop ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy way to do that is to open the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) , and follow the steps :

1. go to Your home folder , there should be .wine directory that contains /drive_c directory, open them

   > kocurr@ux:~$ cd ~/.wine/drive_c
2. Look for folder / files that You would like to copy to Your desktop

   > kocurr@ux:~$ ls
   >   FOLDER Program Files  users  windows
3. Copy folder / files that You wanted to Your desktop for example:
   a) as for directory :

   > cp -r FOLDER/ ~/Desktop/

b) as for files :

> cp FOLDER/file_1 FOLDER/file_N  ~/Desktop/

Comment: lol... you went the better and more advanced route...  and

Answer (score 4):

A GUI option:

There is a tool called "Browse C: Drive" included in wine. If you start this, it opens a regular file manager window in the Wine C: base directory. You can then open the desktop folder in a new window or tab (depending on your file manager and preference) and easily copy your files.

Comment: lol, you went the easy route.... and